# Android: Create an Activity initially hidden, process data while its hidden, then show it only after its ready

Tags: android

I have a two activity application.  One is a "HomePage".  Another is a "DataPage" activity that just contains a webview.  When the user clicks on a button on the HomePage, I show the DataPage and load the URL.  The problem is the URL is a very slow loading page.  I want to solve that problem by creating both activities when my app is open.  The home page will be visible, the DataPage will be hidden.  I will immediately start the WebView of the DataPage so that it loads in the background.  Then when the user clicks on the button, I will reveal the DataPage, with most of its data already loaded.

I dont know how to create an activity in an initially hidden state.  And then bring that activity into the front?  Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Activity` is not in the foreground, then it either has never been created, its in the *Paused* state, or in the *Stopped* state.  You won't be able to have it render itself in the background during any of those times.  You can read more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) which contains the following flow chart of an `Activity's` lifecycle:

[image: Activity Lifecycle Flowchart]

There are a variety of ways to retrieve data through a background thread.  Would it be possible to download the page as a locally cached file, so the DataPage only needs to render the HTML/CSS/JavaScript when it opens?  If the rendering page is the bottleneck, this won't help you much though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an Activity that runs in the background, that's what a `Service` is for. I'd recommend that when your "DataPage" Activity is started, you default the visibility of the WebView to `gone` and display a `ProgressBar` (loading spinner) to indicate that something is happening.

You can use the `setWebViewClient` method on your WebView to provide a custom client that overrides the `onPageFinished` method. When that callback method is triggered you can hide the progress bar (spinner) and show your WebView.

Something like this:

```
WebView view = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
view.loadUrl("http://mydomain.com/");
```